# How can I create a heatmap on a map using only zipcodes

Tags: r, dictionary

I have the dataframe below and I wonder if I can draw a heatmap on a Chicago map using only the zipcodes. `Count` will be used as numeric value.

```
structure(list(Zip = structure(c(15L, 19L, 25L, 27L, 30L, 30L, 
41L), .Label = c("60411", "60415", "60462", "60607", "60608", 
"60609", "60610", "60612", "60613", "60614", "60615", "60616", 
"60617", "60618", "60619", "60620", "60621", "60622", "60623", 
"60624", "60625", "60626", "60628", "60629", "60630", "60631", 
"60632", "60633", "60634", "60636", "60637", "60638", "60639", 
"60640", "60641", "60642", "60643", "60644", "60645", "60646", 
"60647", "60649", "60651", "60652", "60653", "60655", "60656", 
"60657", "60659", "60660", "60707"), class = "factor"), Count = c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), groups = structure(list(
    Zip = structure(c(15L, 19L, 25L, 27L, 30L, 41L), .Label = c("60411", 
    "60415", "60462", "60607", "60608", "60609", "60610", "60612", 
    "60613", "60614", "60615", "60616", "60617", "60618", "60619", 
    "60620", "60621", "60622", "60623", "60624", "60625", "60626", 
    "60628", "60629", "60630", "60631", "60632", "60633", "60634", 
    "60636", "60637", "60638", "60639", "60640", "60641", "60642", 
    "60643", "60644", "60645", "60646", "60647", "60649", "60651", 
    "60652", "60653", "60655", "60656", "60657", "60659", "60660", 
    "60707"), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L,3L, 4L, 5:6, 7L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a mapping between zip codes and geospatial boundaries. Here is an option:

1. [Download shape file for Chicago ZIP boundaries](https://data.cityofchicago.org/Facilities-Geographic-Boundaries/Boundaries-ZIP-Codes/gdcf-axmw). Save file and unzip; I assume the relevant file is at the root of your R working folder.
2. Assuming your `data.frame` with counts and ZIP codes is called `data`, read the shape file and add counts through a left join.

   ```r
   library(rgdal)
   # Make sure the name of the shape file matches the name of the shape file 
   # from the ZIP archive
   shp <- readOGR("geo_export_4e602fd1-be14-4590-8a68-fdbca198af8f.shp")

   # Add count data
   library(dplyr)
   shp@data <- shp@data %>% left_join(data, by = c("zip" = "Zip"))
   ```
3. Example plot using `leaflet`.

   ```
   library(leaflet)
   pal <- colorNumeric("Reds", domain = NULL)
   leaflet(shp) %>%
       addPolygons(
           color = "black", 
           weight = 1, 
           fillColor = ~ pal(Count))
   ```

   [image]

---

### Update

To add a legend, I recommend removing `NA`s from the `Count` column first.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
shp@data <- shp@data %>% 
    left_join(data, by = c("zip" = "Zip")) %>%
    replace_na(list(Count = 0))
```

Then use `addLegend` to add a colour legend

```r
library(leaflet)
pal <- colorNumeric("Reds", domain = NULL)
leaflet(shp) %>%
    addPolygons(
        color = "black", 
        weight = 1, 
        fillColor = ~ pal(Count)) %>%
    addLegend(
        "bottomright", 
        pal = pal, 
        values = ~ Count,
        title = "Count",
        opacity = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: plain and simple thank you. it it possible to have the legend as well? I have added %>% addLegend(position = "bottomright",
        pal = pal, values = ~Count
      )but I did not took exactly what I wanted based on my data

Comment: @firmo23 Please see my edit on how to add a legend. The key is to replace the `NA`s with zeros first.